# ¿Cómo mostrar espacios en Sublime Text 3?

Tags: ide, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Estoy utilizando una versión no registrada de [Sublime Text (3)](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) para jugar con *python*.

Debido a los programas que estoy haciendo son muy básicos para familiarizarme con la sintaxis (funciones básicas, etc.) prefiero usar *Sublime* antes que pasarme a un IDE como *Eclipse*.

Una correcta *indentación* es fundamental en python. Sé que los IDEs (por ejemplo *Eclipse*) pueden mostrar los espacios y las tabulaciones, y distinguir entre ellas, pero no encuentro la manera de configurarlo para ficheros tipo **.py* con *Sublime Text*.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que, al igual que me resalta la sintaxis de un cierto lenguaje, para los **.py* *Sublime Text* me muestre los espacios y tabulaciones?

Comment: Por favor, quita la etiqueta _python_ ya que la pregunta en sí no tiene nada que ver con el lenguaje Python sino con como configurar Sublime Text

Comment: Gracias. Tienes razón. He quitado "python" y añadido "sublimetext" (genérica para el IDE/editor) y "sublimetext3" como especifica de la  versión que estoy usando yo. Gracias de nuevo por el apunte.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ve a `Preferences` > `Settings-Default` y cambia el valor de

```
"draw_white_space": "selection"
```

a

```
"draw_white_space": "all"
```

debe de estar aproximadamente por la línea 150

Comment: Quería mejor si busca esa línea con ctl+f no crees ?

Comment: Suponiendo que no la hayas cambiado y que sublime 3 la traiga... yo lo probé en sublime 2 :)

Comment: Yo tambien lo probe con Sublime 2, por eso la sugerencia :)

Comment: Sublime 3 la trae... Esto funciona (+1) pero no lo he añadido en `Settings-Default`, porque no lo puedo modificar (no sé si es por mi O.S. o por tener sólo la versión de evaluación). La he añadido a `Settings-User` y hace lo esperado. Supongo que la única diferencia estaría en si hubiese más usuarios usando la misma instalación de Sublime. Gracias

Comment: @DiegoAlonso Has hecho bien, modificar los valores por defecto no se recomienda ya que cualquier actualización puede sobreescribirlos.

Answer (score 2):

Además sumado a lo que dijo RusLan, puedes instalar el paquete **codeFormatter** para que te ayude a formatear el código, dependiendo del lenguaje, en este caso Python.

Para eso debes bajar el **package control** y copiarlo en la carpeta **InstalledPackages** que se encuentra en el direcorio raíz de sublime.

Una vez instalado el controlador de paquetes buscar e instalas el **codeFormatter**. 
En base a mi experiencia, como IDE para Python te recomiendo que utilices Geany.Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias. Le echaré un vistazo a _Geany_ cuando empiece a hacer proyectos un poco más serios con python.

Comment: @DiegoAlonso de nada estimado, cualquier cosa no dudes en preguntar. Saludos